# Значение cookie в select value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Имеется следующая форма

```
    <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="city" id="city" class="city" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="archangelsk">Архангельск</option>
            <option value="msk">Москва</option>
       </select>                        
    </form>
```

при отправке которой я хочу выставить значение соответствующей куки, делаю это так

```
 if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
        setcookie('rio_city', $_POST['city'], time()+604800);
    }

//выставим значение, если не установлено
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['rio_city'])) {
        setcookie('rio_city', 'msk', time()+604800);
        $current_city = $_COOKIE['rio_city'];
    }
```

и выставить это значение, как текущее в тот самый select, вот так:

```
<script>
    $(".city").val('<?php echo $_COOKIE['rio_city']; ?>');
</script>
```

Сайт на Wordpress. Форма в header, код про куки - в functions.php, скрипт в footer. Все, вроде бы, работает, но, для того, чтобы значение подставилось в select, после отправки формы(страница при этом перезагружается) нужно перезагружать страницу вручную еще раз. Думаю, проблема в чем-то простом, но додуматься сам не могу. Работает вот [здесь](http://rio.malginovdesign.ru/).

Comment: Открываете http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php и видите там абзац `После передачи клиенту cookie станут доступны через массив $_COOKIE при следующей загрузке страницы.` Если ставите куку через setcookie(), то дальше используете то значение, которое было указана при установке, а не `$_COOKIE['rio_city']`.

Comment: то есть, нужно брать напрямую "$_POST['city']", если нет куки? немного не понял

Comment: Да, но не доверяйте пришедшим данным со стороны. Что `$(".city").val('<?php echo $_COOKIE['rio_city']; ?>');`, что `$(".city").val('<?php echo $_POST['city']; ?>');` выводить опасно. Для экранирования используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: я дополнил php код строкой $_COOKIE['rio_city'] = $_POST['city']; и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Куки работают с заголовками, поэтому устанавливать их надо до того, как будет произведен какой-либо вывод на экран. Для WP рекомендуют устанавливать куки через действие init:

```
add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_cookie' );
```